# How to get rid of keyring Chrome pop-up when I do not know the original password

Tags: linux, chrome

Everytime I start up Chrome on Linux Mint, I am greeted by up to four pop-ups saying "login to unlock keyring". I read an answer [here](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/916) on how to get rid of the keyring pop-up however it requires knowing the original keyring password. The problem is that I do not know the original password as I never set it up (I didn't even know this was a thing before it started asking me to login). I have no idea why it is asking me for a password which I have not set.

Answer (score 0):

Open the applications folder as root -  `/usr/share/applications` and find the launcher for Google Chrome

Open launcher with text editor (gedit, geany, etc.) - Scroll down until you find the line starting with Exec - see below

To the end of the Exec line, add the following text (but before the `%U`)

```
--password-store=basic
```

as shown below

```
Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic %U
```

Scroll down further and repeat for incognito mode if desired.

Be sure to SAVE before closing text editor.

Comment: Maybe give an example (file name) for the Chrome launcher and use that name in the steps following. That would improve the quality of the answer.